# How can I memoize functions, values in React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It's a kinda silly question but can I use useCallback and useMemo in React class (or equivalent solution)? Is it a good practice?

The workaround I found is to use a package named Memoizee: https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee. However, this is a 3rd package (is there any React built-in solution?)

Since my old component is React class, it will take a pretty amount of time to convert it to React Hooks

Comment: @ori-drori No it's not a duplicate, My question is how can I memoize values, (or functions) in React class? All articles on the net are about memoizing in React Hooks

Comment: Your wording specifically says `useCallback` and `useMemo`, so it's a bit misleading. You should change the question, and add some code that you tried. Unless you want to get voted down, and get the question closes for other reasons. However, there're lots of hookless memoize in react questions/answers around.

Comment: I change the title, I think it is clear enough now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `useCallback` it's pretty easy to get. With class properties syntax(to store value between renders) and arrow function expression(to bind `this`) you can do that:

```
 onClick = (e) => { this.setState({ clicked: true }); }
...
 render() {
   ...
   <button onClick={this.onClick}
```

And sure, you can just do that in constructor, if don't want to include babel plugin to support class properties:

```
 constructor() {
   this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
 }

 onClick(e) {
   this.setState({ clicked: true });
 }
```

As for `useMemo` you may utilize any existing package for that, say [lodash's `_.memoize`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize).

Just to highlight: `useMemo` hook is rather for preserving referential equality (say, if some function returns an array or an object than calling that function on each render would provide referentially different result on *each run*). So as alternative to memoization you may just check if some dependencies have been changed in `componentDidUpdate` and once they did - calculate some new data and, say, write it to `state` or directly to `this`(say, if that's timed ID returned from `setTimeouer`)

Comment: It's very helpful